# pass input form value to more than on screen in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Dears ,

I want to pass input value in pid.js screen to  more than on screen 
how can i do it ??

i used the navigate to pass it to service page and it done
but now i want to pass it to another page

```
    class Pid extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {text: ''};
      }

            render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
            return (
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <FormInput placeholder={"PID"} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})} />
            <Button   title='next'
  onPress={() => navigate('service', { text: this.state.text})} >
       </Button>
                    </View>
            );
        }
    }
    export default Pid;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I know, you need this?

```
render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <FormInput placeholder={"PID"} onChangeText=. 
  {(text) => this.setState({text})} />
        <Button   title='next'
    onPress={() => navigate('service', { text: this.state.text})} >
   </Button>
       <Button   title='next'
  onPress={() => navigate('service2', { text: this.state.text})} >
   </Button>
                </View>
        );
```

Comment: @zariwego 
i want  second button in service page that go to service 2 page with the value text , i dont want it in pid page

Comment: Ok, so, in service page you need,  <Button   title='next'
  onPress={() => navigate('service2', { text: this.props.navigation.navigate.getParam('text','default')})} >
   </Button>